# No module named kivy.app

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

So I thought I'd toy around and try and learn Kivy, as it looks interesting. I have just started trying to get one of their examples working:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    pass


class MyPaintApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MyPaintWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        MyPaintApp().run()
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32>python paint.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "paint.py", line 1, in <module>
   from kivy.app import App
ImportError: No module named kivy.app
```

I have installed the latest version of Kivy. I see "app.py in the C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\kivy\kivy folder.

Also, here is my PYTHONPATH:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for n in sys.path:
...     print n
...

C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-2.0.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywin32-218-py2.7-win32.egg

C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\site-packages\plyer-1.1.2-py2.7.egg
C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy_garden-0.1.1-py2.7.egg

C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.2.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\python27.zip
C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\DLLs
C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib
C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27
C:\Kivy-1.8.0-py2.7-win32\Python27\lib\site-packages
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this error message when I named the script `kivy.py`, because python looks first in the current directory to fill the dependency, so it never sees the **real** `kivy` package.

Renaming the script fixed it for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am felling so stupid now... Of course... So logic!

Answer (score 4):

The name of the folder or file cannot be kivy or kivy.py. You need to rename it to another name and it will run ok.

Answer (score 2):

So, I figured it out....I was not being very smart. I'm new to Kivy and I'll answer this for anyone else that is as green as I am. You can't just run this as a python program, doh.

Follow instructions [here] (http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#start-a-kivy-application) and all will be right with the world.

Comment: Can you specify what did you do exactly to solve it? What do you mean with "You can't just run this as a python program", I'm having the same issue.

Comment: The documentation actually says that you should be able to run it with Python like any other python script after you installed the kivy package and dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed kivy using pip you need to add the packages to your environment. In Windows Command Prompt do

```
pip show kivy
```

~Take note of the Location of the module.

Next you can do 1 of two things.

1. Configure any python files you write to refer to the location of your module with sys, use this tutorial for more info: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/environment.html
2. Add the location you found above to your PATH (Windows): https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

2 Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue while running sample app.
I followed simple steps given in : https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html#install-pip

It worked for me.

1. Create the virtual environment
2. Activate the virtual environment.
3. Install Kivy
4. run your .py file

Answer (score 0):

I know I am too late but I hope this will help others, I just did not run it from the command prompt, I opened the python code in my python shell and then pressed run 'F5' and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a virtual environment (venv), make sure you're targetting the the correct Python interpreter. See [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env) for how to to change to the venv interpreter in IntelliJ